# nhibernate/structuremap ObjectFactory.GetInstance ISession fails

Tags: nhibernate, session, structuremap

I'm using [this method](http://www.kevinwilliampang.com/2010/04/06/setting-up-asp-net-mvc-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-structuremap/), for my asp.net mvc application, it works great. But when I use it in a global filter:

```
public class CustomActionFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ISession Session { get; set; }

    public CustomActionFilter()
    {
        this.Session = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISession>();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //call ISession.CreateQuery(...); query.UniqueResult<SomeObject>();

    }        
}
```

this gives '**Session is closed**' error. Any clues to what Im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you, plz, provide a bit more of a StructureMap registration code? For `ISession`, obviously, and everything else related to NHibernate session management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I firstly missed a point about Global Filters.

Sure, it depends on how you instantiate filter.

- When you define filter as attribute, it is instantiated at runtime during controller action invocation and easily injects currently available `ISession` instance.
- But when you try to add it to `GlobalFilterCollection` - you have to (by default) instantiate it like this: `filters.Add(new CustomActionFilter())`. Which means that `CustomActionFilter` constructor is called immediately (on app startup) and tries to resolve a session. As you can imagine, you can't use the same `ISession` for all requests to your MVC App. Therefore, you implement **Session-per-Request** pattern. And should inject new instance for every request.

The simplest thing to do is to move `ISession` resolution (`this.Session = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISession>();` to `OnActionExecuting(...)` method.

The much more complicated way is to create your own `CustomFilterCollection` type and provide own Filter registration infrastructure.

**Update:** The first proposed solution isn't applicable. The problem is that a filter stores state in its property. There are options though:

- Use filters as attributes, not as the `GlobalFilterCollection` elements.
- Implement state concurrency control inside filter itself (i.e. store `Sessions` for all requests in a collection property of global filter and manage them somehow). Bad, smelly approach imho, and not scalable. Session lifetime management should not belong to filters.
- Use different filter registration system (i.e. roll your own implementation of `IFilterProvider` - take [FluentFilters](http://fluentfilters.codeplex.com/) as example of how to do it; or just use it).

Also, it is better to decouple `ActionFilter`s from `FilterAttribute`s.

Comment: Isn't there a further complication, if the filter is used by 2 requests at the same time? One of them may close the session before the 2nd request has finished processing.

Comment: Yeah, it seems you're right. Moreover, `"One of them may close the session before the 2nd request has finished processing"` is wrong at all - 2 different requests should **never** use the same session (except some particular "DB conversation" scenarios). Your Action Filter Attribute stores state (ISession) - and that is the problem. You'd either use this kind of filter just as attributes or decouple actual filters from attributes (in MVC3 filters don't need to be attributes anymore).

Comment: The best option thought would be use of approach like [these FluentFilters](http://fluentfilters.codeplex.com/). That way you can define only type of filter but actual filters will be instantiated on per-request basis.